# Order By calculated value on 1:n relation in QueryDsl with Spring Data

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

i am using Spring Data with QueryDSL. I have a JPQLQuery and want to order it by a calculated value. This calculated value is located in a 1:n relation. Let's say i have the following entities:

- Bill - with a list of pizzas
- Pizza - with an attribute prize and an attribute tax. Additionally there is a boolean flag "favorite", that only one pizza can have.

Now i want to order the bills by the favorite pizza's total price. How can i do that with QueryDSL?

in a JPQL-like pseudo code it would look like this:

`select from Bill b left join b.pizzas p where p.favorite == true order by (p.prize + p.tax)`

With QueryDSL i could use something like the following in the Order clause:

`QBill.bill.any().prize.add(QBill.bill.any().tax).asc()`

The problem here is the any(). That way it does sum up all prizes and taxes, ignoring the where clause.

How can i represent the query i have shown in the pseudo code with query dsl?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query would be

```
QBill bill = QBill.bill;
QPizza pizza = QPizza.pizza;
new JPAQuery(em).from(bill)
                .leftJoin(bill.pizzas, pizza)
                .where(pizza.favorite.eq(true))
                .orderBy(pizza.prize.add(pizza.tax).asc())
                .list(bill);
```

Using `QBill.bill.any()` you will have a new join from bill to pizza and that's something you want to avoid.